# kineticJS children - Jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, kineticjs, resizable

I am using KineticJS v4.3.3, and Jquery 2.0.3 in asp.net MVC application.  I generate a child using:

```
  var wrapper_div = document.getElementById('container1');
    var kinetic_div = wrapper_div.children[0];
    canvaso = kinetic_div.children[0];
    canvaso.setAttribute('id', "panel1");
    context = canvaso.getContext('2d');
```

It works great, however when I add:

```
 $('#container1').draggable().resizable();
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference
```

Would appeciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone might be interested in the solution.  I found when using draggable and resizable, this adds two layer so by changing the children[0] to children[3] it worked.

```
    var wrapper_div = document.getElementById('container1');
    var kinetic_div = wrapper_div.children[3];
    canvaso = kinetic_div.children[0];
    canvaso.setAttribute('id', "panel1");
    context = canvaso.getContext('2d');
```